# Resource Bundle in Google-App-Engine (Struts2)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2, resourcebundle

Im using Struts2 in Google App Enginge.

In `global.properties` file, I have:

```
MESSAGE_SUBJECT = A user sent you a message.
```

In Struts.xml, I have:

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
```

If I have `getText("MMESSAGE_SUBJECT");` in Action, i got the following error:

```
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error: Could not reload resource bundles
    java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private static final java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap java.util.ResourceBundle.cacheList
        at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-1e718b9b5c84cbb1(Request.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:166)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.clearMap(LocalizedTextUtil.java:836)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.reloadBundles(LocalizedTextUtil.java:794)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.reloadBundles(LocalizedTextUtil.java:780)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.findDefaultText(LocalizedTextUtil.java:205)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.getDefaultMessage(LocalizedTextUtil.java:654)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.findText(LocalizedTextUtil.java:534)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.findText(LocalizedTextUtil.java:362)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport.getText(TextProviderSupport.java:202)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport.getText(TextProviderSupport.java:117)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport.getText(ActionSupport.java:102)
        at dating.message.WinkAction.execute(WinkAction.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:43)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
```

The error happens only when deployed, but in development environment, no problem at all.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Put your project in debug mode and try to understand reason why it's unable to resource bundle.

Comment: It's in development mode already. In `struts.xml` I have `<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />` but I haven't figured it out.

Comment: in development which server you are using....have a look http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2125

Answer (score 0):

Struts has no permission to reload container (Jetty), forbidden by AppEngine

Change in struts.properties
struts.i18n.reload=false